# Parse percentage to double

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing

Is there a better way to parse percentage to double like this?

```
Dim Buffer As String = "50.00%"
Dim Value As Double = Double.Parse(Buffer.Replace("%",""), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 100
```

Comment: Why hard-code the percent symbol (%) when you could use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentsymbol.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you are doing it seems good to me.

The only point I would be careful about is that your program is assuming InvariantCulture. Make sure this is actually what you mean. For example it might be better to use the machine's default culture if your string comes from user input rather than a fixed well-defined protocol.

Comment: The Invariant.Culture is just for simplicity of the sample. Stackoverflow has no user input for my sample code :-)

Answer (score 3):

You might vote for this .NET Framework 4 suggestion on Microsoft Connect: [Extend double.Parse to interpret Percent values](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/651185/extend-double-parse-to-interpret-percent-values)

Comment: @dbasnett Sad, it looks like that suggestion was closed without fixing or adequate explanation why they were closing it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with vb but creating a function out of it is already better

**psuedo code:**

```
function PercentToDouble( Buffer )
    return Double.Parse(Buffer.Replace("%",""), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 100;
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

If the percent is user input then

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim pb As New PictureBox
    Dim foo As New gameObj(pb, gameObjType.person)

    Dim sInps() As String = New String() {"50.00 %", "51.00%", ".52", "53", ".54%"}

    For Each sampleInput As String In sInps
        Debug.WriteLine(ConvertPercentToDouble(sampleInput).ToString("n4"))
    Next

End Sub

Private Function ConvertPercentToDouble(s As String) As Double
    Dim Value As Double
    Dim hasPercent As Boolean = s.Contains(System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PercentSymbol)
    Dim whereIsPC As Integer = Math.Max(s.IndexOf(" "), _
                                        s.IndexOf(System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PercentSymbol))
    If Double.TryParse(s, Value) _
        OrElse Double.TryParse(s.Substring(0, whereIsPC).Trim, Value) Then
        If Value > 1 OrElse hasPercent Then Value /= 100 
        Return Value
    Else
        Throw New ArgumentException("YOUR ERROR HERE")
    End If
End Function
```